# How to create a new Java object with new scope in JNI

Tags: java, c, class, scope, java-native-interface

I'm tried below example. I have two native method setMessage and printMessage. I am creating two ClassA object in the main method and  setMessage on a1 object Il get the same message scope on a2 object also(see output).

How to create new ClassA object with the new scope.

ClassA.c

```
#include "ClassA.h"

char * message ;
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassA_setMessage (JNIEnv * env , jobject obj, jstring msg){
    message = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, msg, 0);  
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassA_printMessage  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj){
  printf("%s\n", message);
}
```

ClassA.java

```
public class ClassA { 
    static {
         System.loadLibrary("myapp");          
    }
    public native void setMessage(String msg);
    public native void printMessage();
}
```

ClassB.java

```
public class ClassB   { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassA a1 = new ClassA();
        System.out.print("Print message with out setMessage() By a1 :");
        a1.printMessage();
        a1.setMessage("I am a1"); 
        System.out.print("Print message after setMessage() By a1 : ");
        a1.printMessage();


        ClassA a2 = new ClassA(); 
        System.out.print("Print message with out setMessage() By a2 :");
        a2.printMessage(); 


    a2.setMessage("I am a2");   
    System.out.print("Print message after setMessage() By a2  :  ");
    a2.printMessage();
    }
}
```

:::: Output ::::

```
  Print message with out setMessage() By a1 : (null)
  Print message after setMessage() By a1    :  I am a1
  Print message with out setMessage() By a2 :  I am a1
  Print message after setMessage() By a2    :  I am a2
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear "message" before creating a new object.

Comment: But I need new object with new scope. I wanna use two object at same time .

Comment: Then remove this static

`static {
         System.loadLibrary("myapp");          
    }`
and change it like 
`Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary("myapp");`